# How to solve null is not subtype of bool?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

[image]

Getting error while debugging that that null is not subtype of bool
I not getting it how to do

Comment: Please don't post code just as screenshot, but include it as text in your question.

Comment: please more details

Comment: Please check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Do Change in Your Code

```
Params? query= Params();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are sending null to function that is not null able. for tseting print EndPoints.checkList and query in terminal before function calling.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).